# How do I specify the domain of a quantifier?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, predicate-logic

How do I specify the domain of a quantifier?

> A = {x | x is an animal}
>
> ∀x(Dog(x) → Bark(x))

Is this correct?

> (∀x ∈ A)(Dog(x) → Bark(x))

Comment: Did you mean to write $D=\{x \mid x\ \text{is an animal}\}$?

Comment: @JohnGriffin xD, sorry fixed

Comment: All dogs bark.  For all d in Dogz, d barks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\forall x \in A (Dog(x) \implies Bark(x))$$ is actually a shorthand for 
$$\forall x[x \in A \implies (Dog(x) \implies Bark(x))]$$ which could be read as 'given a thing $x$, if $x$ is an animal then if it is a dog it barks', or in a shorter way 'given any animal $x$, if $x$ is a dog then $x$ barks', so yes, it is correct to specify the domain of your quantifier in that way